# About API document and Devices Action on assistant-sdk-cpp

Tags: c++, google-assistant-sdk

1.Is there any assistant-sdk-cpp develoopemnt API docuument, like hot-word detection ?

2. Is there Device Actions only support for python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ sample is based directly on the service api, which has references here: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/rpc/google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2

It supports server-side features like device actions, but does not support advanced client-side features like hotword detection. You'd need to build or integrate that feature on your own.

Comment: Thank the answer, i had one more question, if we used Linux base embedded system and support python and ALSA, not raspberry pi, can we using the python version SDK to development ?

Comment: You can use the Python implementation of the service API. The thicker client library for the SDK should run, but I wouldn't guarantee it.